# Internal provisioning error if Content-Type is not JSON

Tags: onelogin, scim

I'm trying to integrate my existing *SCIM 2.0* API with *Onelogin*, but during my first test I got an **Internal Provisioning Error**, according to my logs, only one request was made. The one for checking the existence of the user(`GET /Users?filter=userName eq foo@bar.com`).

After several attempts, I noticed the user provisioning worked when that initial request made by Onelogin responded with `Content-Type: application/json`(as in SCIM 1.0) instead of the CT defined in the [SCIM 2.0 specification](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7644#section-3.1), `Content-Type: application/scim+json`.

Is there any way I can tell Onelogin that my API works with SCIM 2.0 and the SCIM content type should be used? If not, should I assume the JSON content type needs to be sent in all my endpoints responses?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a bug on the OneLogin side of things (one I think folks have run into before)

Mind you I think you'll be fine just sending a `Content-Type: application/json` to the various SCIM folks out there as just about everyone (except apparently OneLogin) ignores this header.

If you need further debugging help, feel free to shoot an email to Devsupport@onelogin.com. From there we can get into more specifics around setting up and testing your application (especially if you want to have it as an official application in our catalog)

Cheers

Comment: Thanks for your response! Yes, I plan to submit my application, but I think I can manage to send the `Content-Type` as JSON from my API. For now, everything else seems to be working correctly.